# Derived Class Insertion and extraction operator overloading and Casting between base to derived class

Tags: c++

1. Can I define separately stream insertion and extraction operators of base and derived classes?
2. If we derive class from base class then how can I cast and overload stream insertion and extraction operator?

I have created a class `VehicleType` and `bikeType` and want to overload stream insertion and extraction operator for derived class because I need to read data from file because when I read data from file with variables of class so, I will lost more time. My question is that how I can cast derived class `bikeType` to `vehicleType`.

```
#pragma once
#ifndef vehicleType_H
#define vehicleType_H
#include<string>
#include"recordType.h"
using namespace std;
class vehicleType
{
  private:
    int ID;
    string name;
    string model;
    double price;
    string color;
    float enginePower;
    int speed;
    recordType r1;
  public:
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream&, const vehicleType&);
    friend istream& operator>>(istream&, vehicleType&);
    vehicleType();
    vehicleType(int id,string nm, string ml, double pr, string cl, float 
         enP, int spd);
    void setID(int id);
    int getID();
    void  recordVehicle();
    void setName(string);
    string getName();
    void setModel(string);
    string getModel();
    void setPrice(double);
    double getPrice();
    void setColor(string);
    string getColor();
    void setEnginePower(float);
    float getEnginePower();
    void setSpeed(int);
    int getSpeed();
    void print();
 };
  #endif
  #pragma once 
  #ifndef bikeType_H
  #define bikeType_H
  #include"vehicleType.h"
 #include<iostream>
 using namespace std;
 class bikeType :public vehicleType
   {
     private:
       int wheels;
     public:
        bikeType();
        bool  operator<=(int);
        bool operator>(bikeType&);
        bool operator==(int);
        bikeType(int wls, int id, string nm, string ml, double pr, string 
          cl,float enP, int spd);
        void setData(int id, string nm, string ml, double pr, string cl, 
        float enP, int spd);
        void setWheels(int wls);
        int getWheels();
        friend istream& operator>>(istream&, bikeType&);
        friend ostream& operator<<(ostream&, const bikeType&);
        void print();
         };
        #endif
```

I have defined all functions of base and derived classes but only stream insertion and stream extraction operators could not defined.

Answer (score 1):

Add a virtual function to base class and define it in derived classes.

```
class vehicleType
{
    // ...
    virtual ostream& output(ostream& os) = 0;
};

class bikeType :public vehicleType
{
    // ...
    ostream& output(ostream& os) override
    {
        return os << "I am a bike!";
    }
};
```

Define output operator like this:

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const vehicleType& v)
{
    return v.ouput(os);
}
```

Comment: I have already define function for base class. I want to define function for derived class.

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. Please provide a minimal verifiable example.

Comment: I want to tell you that we cannot make friend function to virtual function.

Comment: @SarmadAli, I still don't get what you are expecting from the community. user2079303 has provided exact answers to your questions. My answer shows a different approach to achieve the same result. However, you haven't accepted any of those.

Answer (score 0):

> 1. Can I define separately stream insertion and extraction operators of base and derived classes?

Yes. As you have done.

> 2. If we derive class from base class then how can I cast and overload stream insertion and extraction operator?

You can use a static cast to a reference to base if you would like to call the extraction operator of the base.

Comment: `ostream& operator<<(ostream& osObject, const busType& 
                 bus)
               {
            osObject << static_cast<vehicleType&>(bus);
           osObject << "\t\t" << bus.seats << "\t\t" << bus.wheels << 
                  endl;
        return osObject;
               }`   I did but compiler giving me error of  "The invalid type 
             conversion  " I did not understand this type of error.